# How to efficiently reuse JSF (1.2) pages and their backing beans?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-1.2

I'm aware that the question is more a question to-be-discussed than to-be-answered, but I wasn't able to rephrase the question to make it more concrete.

I'm currently developing JSF 1.2 based pages and I was thinking about how to efficiently reuse parts of the pages. I came up with the following idea (example scenario):

Page 1 is composed of three parts, the same is true for Page 2.
I extracted the three parts in separate files and I include them on Page 1 and 2 (using `<ui:include />`).

So Page 1 includes Part 1, 2 and 3 and Page 2 includes Part 1, 2 and 3 (they are identical).

At this point I was thinking how to reuse the backing beans and I came up with the following  idea:

Each page has its own backing bean, let's call it Bean 1 (for Page 1) and Bean 2 (for Page 2).

I define an interface for each Part. So I have one interface (called Interface 1) for Part 1, a second interface (called Interface 2) for Part 2 and so on. These interfaces define all methods required by its part. F.ex. if Part 1 requires the attribute "test" (a `String`) in the JSF site (`<h:outputText value="#{bean.test}" />`), Interface 1 defines a method called `public String getTest();`.

So my basic idea is, if Page 1 includes Part 1, its backing bean (Bean 1) must implement Interface 1.
In my scenario, the backing bean of Page 1 would implement Interface 1, 2 and 3. Page 2 would implement Interface 1, 2 and 3 as well.

So up to this point the code in the backing bean's are still redundant, which I want to avoid.
To solve this, I create abstract implementations for Interface 1, 2 and 3, called Abstract Part 1 and so on.

This abstract classes will be extended by Bean 1 and 2. Bean 1 and 2 will only override methods which differ from the abstract implementation (f.ex. methods which are responsible for loading the data - in above sample `public String getTest();` can be overridden to provide different data for Page 1 and Page 2).

So my final solution is quiet complex. Now my "question": Is this a good way to reuse backing beans? Has somebody better solutions?

Kind regards

stupidSheep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am creating a page fragment* that I intend to re-use in multiple pages, I usually create a backing bean just for the fragment and pass any contextual information required to the fragment via params (and Seam DI but that might not be viable for you):

```
<ui:include scr="/common/myfragment.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="property" value="#{pageBean.property}" />
</ui:include>
```

That way your page beans don't need to implement any of the fragment's functionality.

*Sorry for using the term fragment, by which I do not mean a `<ui:fragment>` tag but an arbitrary portion of the page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you explain me how you handle various backing beans for one page? I.e. if you have Page 1 which is composed of 3 parts, and each part has its bean, as well as Page 1. So all in all you have four beans. How does the bean of Page 1 has access to the beans of each part (fragment*)? How do you handle this?

Comment: I do not give the 'Page 1' bean access to the 'part' beans. Instead I give the 'part' beans access to information from the 'Page 1' bean as described above.

Comment: If you want to though, you could make the 'part' beans properties of the 'Page 1' bean and pass the 'part' beans to the fragment as `ui:param`s.

Comment: Today I tried some stuff and I came up with the solution described by you in your second comment:
Each part has its own bean, which is registered in `faces-config.xml` (context is none). The I used the `managed-property` to inject this bean to the 'Page 1' bean. Additionally I pass the part beans to the fragment, as described by you.

If you don't mind, can you explain me how you access the 'part' beans in your 'Page 1' bean if I use the solution described by your first comment? 

Kind regards & many thanks!!

Comment: I don't. By passing the contextual information via DI or `ui:param`s (often the part of the model to be displayed), the 'part' bean can have everything it needs to act correctly. The 'Page 1' bean doesn't usually need to know it exists. Backing beans (controllers) should be lightweight and only facilitate the display of your model, and so aren't usually very complex.